# Maintain DataFrame Index Through Gensim

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, indexing, gensim

Related to: [Getting string version of document by id in Gensim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28488714/getting-string-version-of-document-by-id-in-gensim)

I am implementing `gensim` for document similarity. After retrieving the `gensim` Similarity object index and similarity score for a new document, I would like to trace that index back to the original document in the corpus. Based on the answer in the question above, it looks like there is no built-in way to achieve this.

The df that feeds into my corpus looks like this:

```
id    text
1-23  She loathes apples
1-52  I like rocks
1-43  You like ice cream
1-67  He hates bananas
```

After building the `gensim` model (tweaking it for dataframes from this tutorial: https://www.oreilly.com/learning/how-do-i-compare-document-similarity-using-python), I run the following new document through:

```
id    text
1-98  I like neutrons
```

I can get the max similarity score and the index of the Similarity object with this function:

```
def search(row):
    query = [w.lower() for w in word_tokenize(row)]
    queryBOW = dictionary.doc2bow(query)
    queryTFIDF = tfidf[queryBOW]
    maxSim = max(sims[queryTFIDF])
    index = [i for i, j in enumerate(sims[queryTFIDF]) if j == maxSim]
    return maxSim, index
```

After unpacking the tuple into separate df columns:

```
id    text              maxSim    index
1-98  I like neutrons   0.5678    4
```

The index of the Similarity object does not match the index of the original dataframe.

How would I carry the original dataframe index into the similarity object? Or, how would I carry the `id` field from the original dataframe object into the Similarity object? I understand I have to keep a separate mapping between Similarity object index and original dataframe index - what does that mapping look like?

Desired result:

```
id    text              maxSim    index   originalTextID    originalText
1-98  I like neutrons   0.5678    4       1-52              I like rocks
```